# Visual Studio DataSet Designer Expressions - How to convert Datatime?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset

I'm trying to add a "expression" based column in dataset using the Visual Studio's designer. The data retreived is a Datatime format which will be concatenated with a string from another column.

I managed to do the concatenation and use this field in my code, however, i'd like to be able to reformat the date using the following patern "YY-MM-DD".

http://i49.tinypic.com/11rtzki.jpg

Any idea how I can acheive this?

PS. Do not bother with any method that involves code manipulation outside of the dataset, it would not be worth the trouble considering the use of this new expression field).

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

(Sorry for the bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up editing the SQL query to add a field that did what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong on this but try something like this:

```
string myDate = "20120101" //January 1st, 2012
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);
string myFormattedDate = string.Format("{0:yy-MM-dd}", date)
```

Comment: Yea, I know something like this could work, the problem is that I cannot leave the dataset. If you can override the dataset's output method for the column in question, then yes I could use this code. But I figured theres probably an easy way to simply add a fonction (SQL-Like fonction) in the "Expression" box as shown in the screenshot to acheive the same goal.

If there isnt, how can I override that method to implement this without leaving the dataset code?

(PS, this is a strongly typed DataSet)